# How to get System Keyboard Shortcuts programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I just developed an iOS 8 Custom Keyboard and my users are requesting to be able to import the Keyboard Shortcuts in System Settings.

Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

I thought it was impossible because all apps run in sandbox and does not have access to System Settings. However, this custom keyboard did achieve this.

https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/bai-du-shu-ru-fa-zui-kuai/id916139408?mt=8

It has an option to import Keyboard Shortcuts next time when custom keyboard loads.

Anyone has any idea which API is this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html):

> Every custom keyboard (independent of the value of its
>   RequestsOpenAccess key) has access to a basic autocorrection lexicon
>   through the UILexicon class. Make use of this class, along with a
>   lexicon of your own design, to provide suggestions and autocorrections
>   as users are entering text. The [UILexicon](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILexicon_Class/index.html) object contains words from
>   various sources, including:
>
> - Unpaired first names and last names from the user’s Address Book database
> - Text shortcuts defined in the Settings > General > Keyboard > Shortcuts list
> - A common words dictionary

In particular pay attention to [UILexicon's requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIInputViewController/requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion:)

> Call this method to obtain a UILexicon object containing a basic set
>   of term pairs for use in autocorrection or textual suggestions based
>   on user input. The UILexicon object contains words from various
>   sources, including:
>
> - Unpaired first names and last names from the user’s Address Book database
> - Text shortcuts defined in the Settings > General > Keyboard > Shortcuts list
> - A common words dictionary

Comment: I am aware of this API, but one thing will be how to differ from those different sources, but I will give it a try.